# How to get set of keys having same value from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to know all keys whose values are same.

I have below array:

```
[monday] => 10:00 - 11:00, 
[tuesday] => 11:00 - 12:00,
[wednesday] => 10:00 - 11:00,
[friday] => 10:00 - 11:00,
[saturday] => 11:00 - 12:00,
[sunday] => 14:00 - 15:00,
```

monday/wednesday/friday  = 10:00 - 11:00.

tuesday/saturday = 11:00 - 12:00.

sunday = 14:00 - 15:00.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 4):

You can do a simple `foreach` loop and join a new array depending on values:

```
<?php

$worktimes = array(
    'monday' => '10:00 - 11:00', 
    'tuesday' => '11:00 - 12:00',
    'wednesday' => '10:00 - 11:00',
    'friday' => '10:00 - 11:00',
    'saturday' => '11:00 - 12:00',
    'sunday' => '14:00 - 15:00'
);

$combined = array();
foreach ( $worktimes as $key => $value ) {
    $combined[$value][] = $key;
}

print_r( $combined );

?>
```

Now you have a new array that holds you `key` with all the `values` that match it.

Comment: And how does this not answer the question?

Comment: @bukfixart This does answer the question. Have *you* read the question?

Comment: @bukfixart The resultant array is `Array ( [10:00 - 11:00] => Array ( [0] => monday [1] => wednesday [2] => friday ) [11:00 - 12:00] => Array ( [0] => tuesday [1] => saturday ) [14:00 - 15:00] => Array ( [0] => sunday ) )` which is in fact, the answer of the question.